# Using NDK to build Project in cygwin

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cygwin

Here is the whole procedure that i have followed to configure my project:

-downloaded android-ndk-r8b

-imported my project to eclipse workspace that is tesseract-ocr

-imported tess-two project into eclipse that contains native code. It has some folders one being jni that has android.mk and application.mk

-downloaded and installed cygwin with requirements for ndk usage.

My EclipseProjects workspace is present in drive c and android-ndk-r8b is also in c drive
i open cygwin. write the following command on terminal

```
/cygdrive/c/EclipseProjects/tess-two-master/tess-two/jni
```

this gets me into this directory:

```
Haris Riaz@HarisRiaz-PC /cygdrive/c/EclipseProjects/tess-two-master/tess-two/jni
```

Now i write the following command:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build
```

From my point of view everything i think is pin point still cygwin terminal says:

```
-bash: /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build: No such file or directory
```

instead of building myproject! andbody please tell me if am missing something and what would i do after building the project!

Comment: tell us the output of this command: 'file /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build'

Answer (score 1):

It's probably pointing to another bash.exe in your PATH environment variable. Check your PATH environment variable for possible bash.exe includes like a git installation. cygwin\bin should come first.